# A class for spin up and down particles?

Tags: python, class

So I have a bunch of particles which can be of two kinds let's say "up" and "down". I am new to python but I know that this segregation can be done with the help of a class.

Let's say I have a list:

```
T=np.linspace(0,1,1000)
```

I want each element of this list to be either one of the two particles but I am not sure if I should create two classes with one "kind" each or a single class with two "instances" and assign each element an instance.

In the end, what I want to do is randomly distribute this property of being "up" and "down" over the list T.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not enough info. You most likely don't want 2 instances when dealing with 1000 items - each item should be probably represented by separate instance of a class. But that doesn't mean that having 2 classes is a way to go.
Are the particles relatively similiar and besides the difference of a single property they have the same behaviour? If so, I'd go for single class, 1000 instances and storing the up/down property in some instance attribute.

EDIT:
This is how I would personally implement this with for the current requirements in question:

```
class Particle:
    def __init__(self, posInit, momInit, spin):
        self.posInit = posInit
        self.momInit = momInit
        self.spin = spin
    def momOfT(self, t):
        return self.momInit*(math.cos(t))+self.posInit*(math.sin(t))
    def posOfT(self, t):
        return self.posInit*(math.cos(t))-self.momInit*(math.sin(t))


T = [Particle(posInit = i, momInit = 1-i, spin = random.choice(["up", "down"])) for i in np.linspace(0, 1, 1001)]

print([T[0].posOfT(i) for i in np.linspace(0, 3.1415*2, 1000)])
```

Comment: Yes the particles are similar except with this single property and of course where they individually have a uniquely defined position and momentum.

Comment: Just to complete the information. I am starting with 1000 particles with different positions and momentum (which are functions of time) and some of these particles are up while others are down.

Comment: @Lost added an example of my solution.

Comment: Thank you! But would I be able to evolve the position and momentum now? So basically, can the instances be made functions of time?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pass `time` to a constructor instead of `pos` and `mom` and calculate them from that?

Comment: I mean that I want the positions and momentum to change with time. Since they are instances now I do not know how to do it.

Comment: How did you do it earlier?

Comment: Earlier I simply defined a function of t:  `def dyn(t):
    for i in range(1000):
            
            
        Z[i]=Zinitial[i]*(math.cos(t))+Pinitial[i]*(math.sin(t));
        P[i]=Pinitial[i]*(math.cos(t))-Zinitial[i]*(math.sin(t));`

Comment: Check the edit. Also, at this point the question is straying a bit from the original question so you might want to start a new thread if something about that contrary to your requirements.